# Why check if preventDefault, then preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, events, preventdefault

I'm trying to use the color slider from [this website](http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/), and here's the [source code](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js). What does the following code do: [line 134](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js#L134)

```
if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
```

I know what `preventDefault()` does, but why is it checking if `preventDefault()` then `preventDefault`? Why is there a need to `preventDefault()`?

Also, the line before that checks if:

```
if (target !== this)
```

What's the need for that?

Comment: because not all engines support it.

Comment: Presumably to prevent errors from being thrown in older versions of IE that don't support it.

Comment: Old IE used `window.event.returnValue = false` instead, if I remember correctly.

Comment: preventDefault is preventing MouseDown on a slider, correct? But mouseDown does work. If it wouldn't the color wouldn't change, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just for cross browser support. IE 8 or under won't support `preventDefault`, they use `returnValue`.

```
//check preventDefault function is exists in event handler 'e'
if (e.preventDefault)

    // if browser support preventDefault, call preventDefault();
    e.preventDefault();
```

**Edit:**

`if (target !== this)`

In this code, `target` is clicked object that can points to `div#sliders` and child elements of `div#silders`(R,G,B,H,S,L slider). and `this` points to `div#sliders`.

So that code means "if clicked object is not div#sliders" for RGB,HSL slider works properly

**Edit 2:**

`e.preventDefault()` is exist for slider moves(dragging) perfectly.

for example, if cursor go out slide while you dragging and there is no `e.preventDefault()`, this function will not work properly.

Comment: If you can answer the last 2 questions I wrote in the comments of @mikryz **before** I get the answer, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks! What about the other question I wrote regarding `preventDefault`? He wrote "this is for clicks on those little tickers". What does "little tickers" refer to?

Comment: @Horay check edit 2. i hope you can understand my bad english

Comment: Sure I can understand it! :) I tried it without the `preventDefault()` and it works fine.

Comment: @Horay yup, it will works fine normally. but [this problem](https://gfycat.com/FrequentWeeklyCaribou) can happen when  `preventDefault()` isn't exists

Comment: Oh. I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser support, specifically [older versions of IE](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2012/04/internet-explorer-8-and-event-preventdefault-problem/). It needs to check if the function exists before it calls it to prevent errors.

Comment: If you can answer the last 2 questions I wrote in the comments of @mikryz before I get the answer, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the if clause there is no parentheses. Thus, this is not a function call, but just a check if such a method exists. Thus they just check if method exists and if it does they call it.

As for target, they check what element got this event first. If it's current slider, they ignore the event.

Comment: Thanks for the **complete** answer! What event is it preventing?

Comment: MouseDown on a slider

Comment: But mouseDown does work. If it wouldn't the color wouldn't change, right?

Comment: I guess, this is for clicks on those little tickers which point at current color selection.

Comment: Do you mean the 'R', 'G', 'B' labels?

Comment: Also, regarding `target`, you wrote "If it's current slider, they ignore the event." Does that mean that the function will trigger again with current slider being event.target?